# How to customize the Spring GraphQL Error Response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-graphql

I am developing a project wherein I'm using GraphQL.

The way GraphQL handles errors is not secure as it exposes the application logic and internals.

Default GraphQL error response looks like this:

```json
{
  "errors": [
    {
      // message in my case was a sql query that was leaking info out
      "message": "INTERNAL_ERROR for 2c69042a-e7e6-c0c7-03cf-6026b1bbe559",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "searchByLocation"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "classification": "INTERNAL_ERROR"
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

I tried using the GraphQL [Exception Resolver](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-graphql-error-handling#2-graphql-response-with-handled-exception), which helped me mask the error to some extent.

```json
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Internal Error Occurred",
      "locations": [],
      "path": [],
      "extensions": {
        "error_code": "0001",
        "exception": "INTERNAL_ERROR",
        "message": "Internal Error Occurred"
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

Is there a better way to handle this and further mask the response so that the it contains only the following info:

```json
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "error_code": "0001",
      "exception": "INTERNAL_ERROR",
      "message": "Internal Error Occurred"
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```